# Select row with most recent date per user with 1 condition in JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa, junit

I have this Entity and I want to list for each device the last event with the property message = 1

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_device_event")
@NamedQueries(value = { 
@NamedQuery(name = "DeviceEvent.findWithMessageActive",
            query = "from DeviceEvent as de1 where de1.message = 1 and de1.received = " 
                  + " ( select max(de2.received) from DeviceEvent de2 " 
                  + " where de2.device.id = de1.device.id )  "), )
public class DeviceEvent {
     ..
}
```

But I have an assertion problem in the last *test*, because it considers `device3` as a last event and its not the case.

```
assertTrue ((numDevicesWithActiveMessage+1) == deviceEventService.findWithActiveMessage().size());

DeviceEvent deviceEvent3 = newDeviceEvent();
deviceEvent3.setMessage(1);
deviceEventService.save(deviceEvent3);

DeviceEvent deviceEvent4 = newDeviceEvent();
deviceEventService.save(deviceEvent4);

assertTrue ((numDevicesWithActiveMessage+1) == deviceEventService.findWithActiveMessage().size());
```

Comment: Can you provide your annotations on `DeviceEvent.findWithMessageActive()`, explanation of where you set `received` and expected result?

Comment: I think you should have added deviceEvent4.setMessage(1); since this code assertTrue ((numDevicesWithActiveMessage+1) == deviceEventService.findWithActiveMessage().size()); was looking for an active message but device4 doesn't have any. Thus, the latest one is device3. may this help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume `DeviceEvent.received` is set in `newDeviceEvent()` method and it's set to current time.

In such case as there is no delay between creating `deviceEvent3` and `deviceEvent4`, most probably they will have the same time in `received` field. The query will then choose the maximum of all `received` and according to outer condition it will select both `deviceEvent3` and `deviceEvent4` for which only `deviceEvent3` will match as it has `message` equal to `1`.

So I believe that **because the TEST consider device3 as a Last event** is actually correct (most probably unless the clocks tick between creation of the two events).

Answer (score 4):

Why not create an identity column for each record to be inserted. For an instance, an ID which automatically increment upon insertion (identity). From there, it should be able to return the latest value of that ID and we base our data from the ID being returned?

Answer (score 1):

You have not set  - `deviceEvent4.setMessage(1)`. Hence `deviceEvent3` would be the latest device event and hence your test seems to be considering the correct device event (deviceEvent3) as the latest event

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have added

```
deviceEvent4.setMessage(1);
```

since this code

```
assertTrue ((numDevicesWithActiveMessage+1) == deviceEventService.findWithActiveMessage().size());
```

is looking for an active message but device4 doesn't have any. 
Thus, the latest one is device3.